# Additional Time Needed for Baking Two Loaves of Bread at same time?

Tags: quickbread

How many minutes should you increase the baking time when baking two loaves of beer bread at same time?  Recipe calls for one loaf to bake at 375 for 50-55 minutes.  Not sure how much time to add when baking a second loaf - do not want doughy, raw bread in the middle of the loaf.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Unless your oven is dramatically under powered, you should not need to adjust the bake time at all—and if it is so under powered, maybe because it is a counter top oven, you should only bake one loaf at a time.

Put the loaves in the oven with at least a hand's width of distance or so, allowing the air to circulate between the loaves.

Note that bread should be cooked until it is done, not just to a certain amount of time.   Your recipe should provide a doneness test such as a target internal temperature (preferably), or how to gauge by the color of the crust development.