# Additional Cooking Time When baking more than one loaf of quick bread

Tags: baking, bread, cooking-time, quickbread

How much time would I need to increase cooking banana quick bread if I am cooking three loaves together.  Time for one is 40 -45 minutes at 350 degrees. I am a baking novice.  Advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Additional Time Needed for Baking Two Loaves of Bread at same time?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/40456/additional-time-needed-for-baking-two-loaves-of-bread-at-same-time)

Comment: Voting to leave open, because while the answers are exactly the same, it is not obvious that quick bread behaves identically to regular bread prior to asking.

Answer (score 3):

See:

[Additional Time Needed for Baking Two Loaves of Bread at same time?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/40456/additional-time-needed-for-baking-two-loaves-of-bread-at-same-time)

Banana bread and beer bread are the same in this aspect.  Multiple loaves will not require a change in baking time if your oven has reasonable total heat output.