# Can I bake 2 small cakes at the same time?

Tags: baking, cake

I have to bake 3 small white cholocate mudcakes and put them together to make the final butt shaped cake, which I will ganache and fondant. I have to bake 1 rectangle cake (for the back) and 2 half hemisphere round cakes (for the cheeks).

I have one rectangle pan 13cmx24cm and one 16cm half hemisphere round pan. I was wondering if I could bake the rectangle and one half round cake at the same time in the middle rack of my fan force oven or will that be a risk and make the cakes dry or undercooked? I usually bake them at 150 degrees.

Comment: How deep will the batter be in each?

Comment: I think about 3/4ths in both the pans. They're almost the same height/depth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you monitor each cake for doneness individually, there is no reason not to bake them  together—assuming they both need the same temperature.

If the sizes are radically different (in terms of the thinnest dimension, which is usually the depth) you may need to adjust temperature to control crust formation during the time it takes the cakes through to the center.

If the cakes are close in depth, they should bake in approximately equal times.

You may wish to use cake strips or aluminum foil to protect the thing easily burned permiter of a hemispherical cake.

Note that 150 C (300 F) is an atypically low temperature for baking a cake.

See related:  [Additional Cooking Time When baking more than one loaf of quick bread](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/40490/additional-cooking-time-when-baking-more-than-one-loaf-of-quick-bread/40493#40493)

Comment: Should've mentioned, its a mudcake, which is generally baked at a low temperature

Comment: If it is typical for your recipe, then cool; the main thing is thta if the two layers are about the same depth, they should require the same time at a given temperature.